# When to use "return result" and when to use "self.result"

Tags: python

Is there any good rules or practices for when you should return something from the function and when you should set the result as a variable(self.result)?

Say you have class where the main objective is to do some calculations, maybe something like:

```
class Calculations:
    def __init__(var1, var2, var3):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    def calc1(self):
        self.result1 = self.var1 + self.var2

    def calc2(self):
        self.result2 = self.var2 + self.var3

    def final_calc(self):
        self.calc1()
        self.calc2()
        return self.result1 / self.result2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calcObject = Calculations(10, 15, 20)
    result = calcObject.final_calc()
```

Is this considered very bad practice? I agree that it don't make much sense in this specific example, but as the calculations grows more complex, I use the results and variables from one functions in several other functions – and I find myself passing lots variables back and forth between functions.

Comment: You need to think of it in terms of *state of the object*. Should a method *modify the object's state* or merely return a value based on the current state of the object?

Comment: To the very accurate explanation by @deceze I would only add that if the intention is to modify the object state, you should of course assign a new value to `self.whatever` but it doesn't prevent you from returning this value as well, if it makes sense in the particular case.

Comment: @deceze So there's nothing wrong in or considered bad practice creating a class the way I did, if I think it makes sense in my case? For example if the return values are getting reused several places?

Comment: Note that Python convention, though, is to return `None` when mutating an object, rather than (say) a reference to the object itself. (Cf `list.append`) That isn't to say that a method whose purpose is to return a value cannot *also* mutate the object in some way, just that `None` is preferable for methods that *primarily* mutate the object.

Comment: For your code, it would be far more natural for `calc1` and `calc2` to simply return the sum (instead of setting a new attribute); then `final_calc` would simply return `self.calc1() + self.calc2()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To decide whether a method should store data in properties and/or `return` it, use some heuristics:

1. Is the method supposed to **modify the object's state**? Properties are not merely things to store calculation results on to pass them between methods; any value stored in a property contributes to the *state* of the object. Does it make sense for the method to change that state?
2. Is the method expected to produce a value? A method like `set_foo(...)` is probably not supposed to produce any new values, a method like `get_foo()` or `calculate()` probably is.
3. Do you have logical dependencies between methods? For your `final_calc`, you *must* call `calc1` and `calc2` first before `result1` and `result2` are available. There is no obvious connection between these method calls and those properties. That would all be a lot more explicit and less error prone like this:

   ```
   def final_calc(self):
       result1 = self.calc1()
       result2 = self.calc2()
       return result1 / result2
   ```

   You're even freeing yourself up to write `return self.calc1() / self.calc2()`.
4. All the properties which will ever exist should be declared in `__init__`, methods should merely change the values of those properties. Your object shouldn't suddenly sprout new properties after calling a method.

Comment: Thanks, exactly that kind of answer I was looking for! However, if I'm going to use result1 and result2 in another function and maybe do some plotting with them at the end, should I then do the calculations over and over again? Or would it then make sense to do these calculations in the __init__ method? Keep in mind that this is an example; IRL the methods may take lots of args and have multiple returns. And they may also be time consuming.

Comment: Then perhaps you want to split all this up into several classes. One class that takes some initial values, and which has a `calculate` method, and returns a new object with the results, which you can reuse.